# boost 1.55.0 asio, TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, where?

Tags: tcp, boost-asio

I'm investigating boost 1.55.0 asio library.
I'm trying to find out way to increase MSS (Maximum Segment Size) for TCP socket.

I guess this option should be set up via `acceptor.set_option(...)` method or something similar, but I could not find, how this option is called in terms of asio.

I have looked up inside boost folder with the following queries:

`grep -ircl --include=*.{c,cpp,h,hpp} "MSS"`

`grep -ircl --include=*.{c,cpp,h,hpp} "TCP_MAXSEG"`

but found nothgin. Other searching is also had no suceess.

Is it possible at all?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that I'm confused now even more. It's a bit another question but related to this up to a point.

As far as I know MSS parameter is responsible for maximum segment size. So if MSS = 1460 than IP packages should NOT be reassembled (at least to Minimum MTU size).

In my case I have simple echo client server application.

```
void ProcessClientConnection(tcp::socket& clientSocket)
{
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    char data[SIZE];
    boost::system::error_code error;


    size_t readBytes;
    while ((readBytes = clientSocket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error)) > 0)
    {
        if (boost::asio::error::eof == error) {
            exit(0);
        }

        cout << data << "[" << readBytes << "]" << endl;

        boost::asio::write(clientSocket, boost::asio::buffer(data, strlen(data) ));
    }
}
```

and client

```
char pTest[2000];
for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    pTest[i] = 'A';
}
cout << pTest << endl;
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(pTest, strlen(pTest)));
```

So as you can see I'm trying to send 2000 bytes at once. I was expecting that this data will be reassemled to 2 packages ( the first one to 1460 & the second one 40 byte, it is approximatly since I don't count TCP & IP headers ), but instead I have 4 packages at all. First thee is 576 bytes and the last one 272. The question what am I missing here?

tcpdump output (hand-shake), as you can see MSS is 65495 (I guess becuase client & server are running in one environemnt and ethernet MTU is NOT used )

`17:44:37.913419 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [S], seq 47119026, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 23401141 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:44:37.913431 IP 10.0.2.15.9999 > 10.0.2.15.36725: Flags [S.], seq 2495807352, ack 47119027, win 1152, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141,nop,wscale 0], length 0
17:44:37.913441 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 0`

here is the communication packages:

`17:44:37.914768 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [.], seq 1:577, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 576
17:44:37.914811 IP 10.0.2.15.9999 > 10.0.2.15.36725: Flags [.], ack 577, win 1152, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 0
17:44:37.914840 IP 10.0.2.15.9999 > 10.0.2.15.36725: Flags [P.], seq 1:577, ack 577, win 1152, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 576
17:44:37.914895 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [P.], seq 577:1153, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 576
17:44:37.914914 IP 10.0.2.15.9999 > 10.0.2.15.36725: Flags [.], ack 1153, win 1152, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 0
17:44:37.914972 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [.], seq 1153:1729, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 576
17:44:37.914990 IP 10.0.2.15.9999 > 10.0.2.15.36725: Flags [.], ack 1729, win 1152, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 0
17:44:37.915040 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [.], ack 577, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 0
17:44:37.915047 IP 10.0.2.15.9999 > 10.0.2.15.36725: Flags [P.], seq 577:1729, ack 1729, win 1152, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 1152
17:44:37.915065 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [P.], seq 1729:2001, ack 577, win 351, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 272
17:44:37.915128 IP 10.0.2.15.36725 > 10.0.2.15.9999: Flags [.], ack 1729, win 1024, options [nop,nop,TS val 23401141 ecr 23401141], length 0`

Comment: Why? The TCP MSS is automatically determined by the path MTU. What makes you think you can determine a better value?

Comment: I have sent data from local interface to local interface ( e.i client & server is running under same machine in Virtual Box. Ubuntu 13.10. MSS = 576 bytes instead of 1460 ( MTU - IP4 HEADER- TCP HEADER).

Comment: And the second reason is just academic interest

Comment: So you want to reduce it?

Comment: I'd like to increase that up to 1460.

Answer (score 0):

`asio`'s great but it's missing a few features for setting up socket options and this appears to be one of them. See: [can you set SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO socket options in boost asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292997/can-you-set-so-rcvtimeo-and-so-sndtimeo-socket-options-in-boost-asio) for another.

However, since this is an integer option you should be able to use `asio::set_option` as below:

```
int size(1460);
socket.set_option(boost::asio::detail::socket_option::integer<SOL_SOCKET, TCP_MAXSEG>(size));
```

Comment: Yeap, seems that is true.